# When trying to configure data guard broker I'm getting Error: ORA - 12154 : TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, listener, dataguard, tnsnames

I'm trying to setup data guard broker in my production instance. I have duplicated the primary database to standby database successfully. I've added primary database to data broker configuration and when I'm trying to add standby database following error is getting

```
DGMGRL> ADD DATABASE 'orcl_standby' AS CONNECT IDENTIFIER IS orcl_standby maintained as physical;
ERROR: ORA - 12154 : TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Tnsping from primary db to standby db and vice-versa is successful. I'm able to connect primary db from standby db using `sqlplus sys/password@orcl as sysdba` but when trying to connect to standby db from primary db, error is getting like

> ORA - 12154 : TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Tried out all possible solutions.

Below is my tnsnames.ora file

```
    ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.25.42)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
      (SID = orcl)
      (UR = A)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL_STANDBY=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.25.44)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl_standby)
      (SID = orcl_standby)
      (UR = A)
    )
  )
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The error is self-explananatory, `orcl_standby` can not be resolved. Put it into `tnsnames.ora`.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I've already added it to my tnsnames.ora file. Please find the tnsnames.ora which I have posted along with question.

Answer (score 0):

The part after `IDENTIFIER IS` must be a connection to the database. You should replace the `orcl_standby` with something like `'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)
(HOST=<server of the Standby>)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<the SID of the Standby>)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))'`.

Comment: Is this the way to add standby database?                                                     ADD DATABASE 'orcl_standby' AS CONNECT IDENTIFIER IS '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)
(HOST=<server of the Standby>)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<the SID of the Standby>)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))';

Comment: This is how I did it. It is the information that you normally put in the `tnsnames.ora` file.